# How to inherit attribute for hidden/show form field

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a form with fields that I have hidden with a drop down function, but I want the fields when displayed alone to require all fields to be completed.

I have tried to set required attribute at the controller page and also on the form page, but it will require that the user fills out the field even if it is visible or not:

```
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row-fluid text-right" id="degreeBtn1">
                                        <input type="button" class="addDegree2" value="+ Add Degree" />
                                    <hr style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" />
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="row-fluid text-right" id="degreeBtn2">
                                        <input type="button" class="addDegree3" value="+ Add Degree" />
                                        <input type="button" class="removeDegree2" value="- Remove Degree" />
                                    <hr style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row-fluid text-right" id="degreeBtn3">
                                        <input type="button" class="removeDegree3" value="- Remove Degree" />
                                    <hr style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" />
                                    </div>
```

How to make it compulsory to complete all fields when the second set of certifications is revealed?

Comment: Please show your code where you hide/show the 2nd set of input fields.

Comment: Hello Vickel, I have edited the question to include the code

Comment: I was referring to your javascript code, and please clean up your example and leave only the necessary part to explain your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: hello vickel, i have edited the code again